# Deploying ear file in JBoss 6.2

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

We have a EAR file which is working fine on our Wildfly server and is accessible through `http://localhost1:8080/proj`

Due to backward compatibility reasons (with another tool) we have had to install JBoss 6.2 and deploy the EAR on JBoss. Although the EAR deploys without any error, it returns 404 error when I go to `http://localhost2:8080/proj`.

No errors in logs are displayed either:

> JBWEB000067: Status report
>
> JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

Do I need to rebuild the code with some changes? I would assume the same EAR file would have worked. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this JBoss EAP 6.2? What version of WildFly were you using?

Comment: What version did you compile for? AFAICT JBoss 6.2 doesn't support JAVA 8 (see [here](http://blog.akquinet.de/2015/02/22/red-hat-jboss-eap-6-4-now-supports-java-1-8-jdk-8/))

Comment: Yes its JBoss EAP 6.2, we have Wildfly 9.0.2 and we are using JDK 1.7

Comment: Hi,Did you get any solution for this. We are also facing same issue